# Mifare Plus Card Activation and Personalization

Tags: nfc, mifare

I finally got all the NDA documents required to know how to communicate with the Mifare Plus (X) cards I have. However, I still have a couple of questions that were not answered by the docs so would appreciate any help. I realise the information may be under NDA, in which case could you please point me to the information rather than stating it outright. The questions are:

1. The docs mention activation into the ISO 14443-4 mode. How do I do this?
2. Is there a way to check the current security level of the card?
3. Is there a way to check whether personalisation of a card has occurred?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to 1.: Send a RATS command, as defined in ISO 14443-4

Answer to 2.: Check Table 6 in [AN10833 "MIFARE Type Identification Procedure"](http://www.nxp.com/documents/application_note/AN10833.pdf)

Answer to 3.: In general, no.

Comment: Thanks for the answers NFC guy, but I can't find what I need to send for the RATS. Would you be able to point me towards where this is specified?

Comment: This depends on your card reader, likely. It either sends it automatically or you have to configure the reader to send it. As RATS is a very low-level command, you typically do not send it manually.

Comment: I'm doing this all on Android. There aren't any specific commands for Mifare Plus on Android, so I'm having to send byte code commands directly, so I think I do have to send it manually? I can't find what to send though.

Comment: For SL0 and SL3, activation to -4 is done automatically by the NFC controller, so you do not need to do anything. For Sl1 and SL2, you could do `connect()` and send a RATS command as `{(byte)0xE0, (byte)0x80}` using `transceive()`. It is probably best to send a DESELECT command (`{(byte)0xC2}`) after you're done and do `close()` and `connect()` to bring the tag back to a state in sync with what the NFC controller expects. You may also want to check out the NXP TagInfo app in the Play Store as a reference.